# Rails: link_to with do block doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, helper, link-to

When 'link_to' is used without block it works perfectly:

```
<%= link_to "Ololo", {controller: "posts", action: "upvote", id: post.id}, method: :put, remote: true, class:"nav-link" %>
```

But when I try to use block it ends up with error:

```
        <%= link_to {controller: "posts", action: "upvote", id: post.id}, method: :put, remote: true, class:"nav-link" do %>
            <%= image_tag('icons/candy.svg', alt: "Candies", class:"rounded-circle icon-nav") %> 
            <%= post.get_upvotes.size %> 
        <% end %>
```

And here is the error message:

```
SyntaxError (/home/alex/test/app/views/application/_votes_exp.html.erb:5: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}'
...r.append=  link_to {controller: controller_name, action: "up...
...                               ^
/home/alex/test/app/views/application/_votes_exp.html.erb:5: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '}'
...troller_name, action: "upvote", id: entity.id}, method: :put...
...                               ^
/home/alex/test/app/views/application/_votes_exp.html.erb:5: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
...pvote", id: entity.id}, method: :put, class:"nav-link", remo...
...                               ^
/home/alex/test/app/views/application/_votes_exp.html.erb:5: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
...method: :put, class:"nav-link", remote: true do @output_buff...
...                               ^
/home/alex/test/app/views/application/_votes_exp.html.erb:49: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input):
```

So it seems like it doesn't understand literal hash, however, I'm too newbie to figure out what's wrong... Any help is appreciated!

P.S.: I can't remove literal hash, because link_to is messing up with css class (adds class as a part of address). Also I have to use older argument style instead of something like 'upvote_post_path' because controller name is represented by variable (in my example it is reduced for readability of the code)

**UPDATE:**

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: "home#index"

  resources :posts do 
    member do
      put "upvote", to: "posts#upvote"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You could pass the route instead passing controller, action and id. Can you add your routes?

Comment: Yes, sure! I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opening brace in things like:

```
some_method { a: 'b' }
```

is ambiguous. The `{` could be opening a block as in `a.each { ... }` or it could be opening a hash literal. You think it is the latter but Ruby thinks it is the former and that's where the error comes from.

The easiest solution is to use method-calling-parentheses:

```
<%= link_to({controller: "posts", action: "upvote", id: post.id}, method: :put, remote: true, class:"nav-link") do %>
           ^--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

You could also use a variable to move the opening brace elsewhere:

```
<% upvote_post = { controller: 'posts', action: 'upvote', id: post.id } %>
<%= link_to upvote_post, method: :put, remote: true, class:"nav-link" do %>
```

This one:

```
link_to "Ololo", {controller: "posts", ...
```

works fine because the first argument (`"Ololo",`) removes any ambiguity by telling Ruby that it is parsing an argument list.

Comment: Thank you very much! The second way worked perfect. However, the first one (with parentheses) caused an error: SyntaxError (/home/alex/test/app/views/application/_votes_exp.html.erb:4: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...tion: "upvote", id: entity.id}, method: :put, remote: true, ...